# Grid of counts by row and column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, crosstab

I'm really struggling to create a simple grid which I can provide to non-technical team members so they can easily look up the number of people in our SQL customer database based on any two demographic characteristics.

For example, we frequently get questions like "how many people in the database are Male aged 36-45" or "how many people aged 18-25 on our database are emailable". With a lookup grid they will be able to answer these for themselves.

The actual data has lots of variables so the real grid is likely to be large but a simplified example of the source data table has 1 row per customer (~3m rows) with the following columns:

```
party_id        -- Customer ID #
, gender        -- 'Male'/'Female'/'Unknown gender'
, age           -- '18-25'/'26-35'/'36-45'/'46-55'/'56-65'/'66-80'/'Unknown age'
, emailability  -- 'Emailable'/'Not Emailable'
```

The results grid will have the same rows and columns with a count of customers in each cell (i.e. the count of people who satisfy both the row and the column criteria). In this example the rows and columns would be:

```
Male
Female
Unknown gender
18-25
26-35
36-45
46-55
56-65
66-80
Unknown age
Emailable
Not emailable
```

To look up the number of people who satisfy any two criteria, you would just need to find the intersection on the grid (in the first question above, this is the intersection of row:"Male" and column:"18-25" or row:"18-25" and column: "Male").

This didn't sound like it should be a difficult problem but I'm completely stumped. I thought it would be solved by Pivots but I couldn't figure out a way to cross-tabulate more than 2 variables. SQL is likely not the right tool for this job either but there's not many other tools available to me right now so if possible I'd like to find a SQL solution but let me know if you know of better options.

I was surprised not to find an existing solution here but I might not be using the right search terms so apologies if this has already been answered.

Thanks!

--EDIT--
As requested here's some sample data:

```
party_id |gender |age     |Emailability  |
---------|-------|--------|--------------|
1        |Male   |18-25   |Not Emailable |
2        |Female |Unknown |Emailable     |
3        |Unknown|36-45   |Emailable     |
4        |Male   |36-45   |Not Emailable |
5        |Male   |56-65   |Emailable     |
6        |Female |26-35   |Emailable     |
7        |Male   |18-25   |Emailable     |
8        |Unknown|18-25   |Not Emailable |
9        |Male   |66-80   |Emailable     |
10       |Female |26-35   |Emailable     |
```

Based on this example data the first few rows of the grid filled in would look like this (I've had to drop the emailability columns because of the page width but they would be included too):

```
                   Male Female Unknown Gender 18-25 26-35 36-45 46-55 56-65 66-80
    Male           5    0      0              2     0     1     0     1     1     
    Female         0    3      0              0     2     0     0     0     0       
    Unknown gender 0    0      2              1     0     1     0     0     0     
    18-25
    26-35
    36-45
    46-55
    56-65
    66-80
    Unknown age
    Emailable
    Not emailable
```

To clarify as I think it caused some confusion, I'm not trying to create a view for other database users - I'm hoping to create an output that I can export to excel for non-technical people to use as a handout/cheat sheet. It may be that this grid can't be set up as planned using SQL alone but due to the size of the dataset and limited numbers of tools I am hoping that it could be done in SQL. Thanks again for any suggestions.

Comment: It's not quite what you're asking, but this is typically a good time to use views. Hide the complex query so the business user can just write simple SELECT * WHERE whateverTheyWantInACannedField.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately there's only 2 of us with access to the DB and about 50 people with questions so views won't be useful.

Comment: The age criteria can be easily solved by using case expresions: (case when 18 <= age and age <= 25 then 1 else 0 end) as "18-25", and so on

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why views aren't useful: you can make a view, and all the users can simply make something like "select * from theView where "18-25" = 1. In that case, it will filter all the people within that age range.

Comment: Thanks Raul, I've already grouped the age ranges into categorical variables (18-25,26-35 etc.), the problem I have is how to get a count of every categorical variable against every other categorical variable.

Regarding views, they don't have database access so won't be able to use the views. I would use something like Power BI or Tableau to allow them to select their criteria but these tools aren't available.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data. It's unclear as to if what your table structure actually is. I certainly hope it's not a denormalized grid

Comment: So, I'm having trouble understanding what you are working with. Is it a grid of binary indicators? I proposed some sample data in an edit.

Comment: Thanks all, I've added some example data. I can set up the data however would be useful (e.g. flags for each categorical variable) but this is how I set up the data when I was trying to solve the problem for myself.

Comment: This just screams of needing to use a third party grid. I am guessing you are doing something like a grid in dotnet? Find a third party solution that allows for filtering. Something like DevExpress or Telerik. Those both allow for use defined custom filtering that can get as complex as the end user wants. Unless you have a very defined set of filters for the end user doing this yourself in t-sql could prove pretty challenging.

Comment: @user9794690 Why are you trying to use SQL for this if the consumers don't have access? It looks like this is easy for a non-technical person to do in an Excel pivot table. Can you just set up a spreadsheet with a pivot table they can fiddle around with?

Comment: I am hoping to use SQL to produce the table so that it can be exported and provided as an excel output to the people who need it. I would use excel to produce the grid but the data set is too large (~3m rows). I would also have used something like Tableau or PowerBI to create a filterable dashboard but the licenses sadly aren't available. I couldn't think of a better way to do this with those limitations but I'm definitely open to suggestions. Thanks for your suggestions so far.

Comment: Sean, thanks for the suggestions but this really isn't anything as technical as that. I just want to provide a handout that people can use to quickly look up the number of people in our database that satisfy any one or two criteria to fend off the simpler questions we get.

Comment: I don't think these requirements are compatible. You need a solution that will scale to 3 million records for analysis by non-technical users without DB access and have no options for specialized tools. If you can get a finite list of the metrics they care most about you can certainly create and provide custom extracts, but if you want them to be able to perform ad-hoc analysis one of your requirements has to give.

Comment: Thanks Error_2646, you could be right that SQL just isn't able to do this kind of analysis/reporting (I know, I know... That's not what it's meant for!) - if anyone has suggestions of (preferably free) tools that could produce a report like this please can you point me in the right direction?